# Are there any other ways to record iotcl calls besides strace?

Tags: linux, ioctl, strace

I'm trying to see if certain ioctl calls get called when I call a function(this is on linux).There no way to cause the kernel to write a log with this sort of data, is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On recent kernel, and if kernel is configured with support for tracing and dynamic tracing, [ftrace](http://lwn.net/Articles/322666/) can probably do what you need.

Another option is to write an ioctl wrapper, load it using [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick), and intercept the interesting ioctl in your wrapper.